# Predicate logic problem using natural deduction

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I have the following clauses:

$1. \forall x ({Ax \rightarrow Bx})$

$2. \forall x (({{Cx \wedge Bx }) \rightarrow Dx})$

$3. \forall x \exists y ({Cy \wedge Ryx})$

$4. \forall x \forall y ({({Ryx \wedge Dy }) \rightarrow Dx})$

And I need to prove:

$\forall x (({{ \forall y ({Ryx \rightarrow Ay })}) \rightarrow Dx})$

Using natural deduction.

I've tried to manipulate #4 but could not get it to look like the expected clause. Any clue is appericiated.

Comment: You need to clarify whether you mean $$\forall x~(\bigg(\forall y~(Ryx \implies Ay)\bigg) \implies Dx)$$ or $$\forall x~(\forall y~\bigg((Ryx \implies Ay) \implies Dx\bigg))$$

Comment: @DanielV Given the parentheses, I think he means $$\forall x\forall y(a(x,y) \implies Dx)$$ where we have $$a(x,y)=Ryx \implies Ay$$ This would be the latter of your statements.

Comment: His choice of parenthesis in the conditions and the presence of an existentially quantified condition (3) makes the former seem more likely to me.  I guess I'll just have to solve both cases and figure out which was intended.

Comment: @DanielV Oh, I see now. Yes, the former is definitely easier to prove. I'm having some trouble with the latter.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't be sure myself. But misreading it may have been one of the reasons I couldn't solve it

Comment: @Mugen You should always always always have an informal proof in mind before you attempt any kind of formal proof.  You must have a reason to believe the statement is true.

Comment: Well I checked and the intended clause is indeed the first one. @DanielV I'm missing the intuition for even an informal proof here. Mind pushing me in the right direction?

Comment: @Mugen Just try out relations that match the conditions and see if they hold in the conclusion.  Try out a bunch until you have a general idea what is going on.

Comment: I deleted my last 2 suggestions given in the comments because they were totally wrong.  See my answer for a better approach please.

Answer (score 2):

$$\newcommand{\DeductionBox} [1]{\begin{array} {l|} #1 \\ \hline \end{array}}$$

The basic idea of the proof is, loosely:

> ```
> for a free x, there is a set of ys satisfying Ryx
> for all of those ys, Ay holds by assumption, and thus By holds
> for at least one of those ys
>   Cy holds
>   so for that y, Dy holds 
> If Dy holds for some y, then Dx holds for the y
> ```

$$\begin{array} {l}
\begin{array} {rlr}
(1) & \forall \langle x,~ Ax \implies Bx \rangle                                          & \text{Given} \\
(2) & \forall \langle x,~ Bx \land Cx \implies Dx \rangle                                 & \text{Given} \\
(3) & \forall \langle x,~ \exists \langle y,~ Cy \land Ryx \rangle ~ \rangle              & \text{Given} \\
(4) & \forall \langle x,~ \forall \langle y,~ Ryx \land Dy \implies Dx \rangle ~ \rangle  & \text{Given} \\
\end{array}\\
\\
\DeductionBox{
  \begin{array} {rlr}
  \quad (5) & \forall \langle y,~ Ryx \implies Ay \rangle      &  \text{New Assumption}              \\
  \end{array} \\
  \\
  \DeductionBox{
    \begin{array} {rlr}
    \quad \quad (6)  & Cy \land Ryx                                         & \text{New Assumption}                              \\
    \quad \quad (7)  & Ryx                                                  & \land-\text{Elimination of }(6)                    \\
    \quad \quad (8)  & Ryx \implies Ay                                      &  \forall-\text{Elimination of }(5)                 \\
    \quad \quad (9) & Ay                                                    & \text{Modus Ponens of }(7)  \text{ and } (8)       \\
    \quad \quad (10) & Ay \implies By                                       & \forall-\text{Elimination of }(1)                  \\
    \quad \quad (11) & By                                                   & \text{Modus Ponens of }(9) \text{ and } (10)       \\
    \quad \quad (12) & Cy                                                   & \land-\text{Elimination of }(6)                    \\
    \quad \quad (13) & By \land Cy                                          & \land-\text{Introduction of }(11) \text{ and }(12) \\
    \quad \quad (14) & By \land Cy \implies Dy                              &  \forall-\text{Elimination of }(2)                 \\
    \quad \quad (15) & Dy                                                   & \text{Modus Ponens of }(13) \text{ and } (14)      \\
    \quad \quad (16) & Ryx \land Dy                                         & \land-\text{Introduction of }(7) \text{ and }(15)  \\
    \quad \quad (17) & \forall \langle y,~ Ryx \land Dy \implies Dx \rangle & \forall-\text{Elimination of }(4)                  \\
    \quad \quad (18) & Ryx \land Dy \implies Dx                             & \forall-\text{Elimination of }(17)                 \\
    \quad \quad (19) & Dx                                                   & \text{Modus Ponens of }(16) \text{ and } (18)      \\
    \end{array}
  } \\
  \\
  \begin{array} {rlr}
  \quad (20) & \exists \langle y,~ Cy \land Ryx \rangle   &  \forall-\text{Elimination of }(3)                               \\
  \quad (21) & Dx                                         &  \exists-\text{Elimination of }(20) \text{ and } (6) \vdash (19) \\
  \end{array}
} \\
\\
\begin{array} {rlr}
(22) & \forall \langle y,~ Ryx \implies Ay \rangle \implies Dx                              &  \text{Deduction of }(5) \vdash (21) \\
(23) & \forall \langle x,~ \forall \langle y,~ Ryx \implies Ay \rangle \implies Dx \rangle  &  \forall-\text{Introduction of }(22) \\
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

The possible parsing of the original question, $\forall \langle x,~ \forall \langle y,~ (Ryx \implies Ay) \implies Dx \rangle ~\rangle$, is not provable, which can be established with the model:

$$\Omega = \{1,~ 2\}$$
$$R = \{(1,~ 1),~ (1,~ 2),~ (2,~ 1),~ (2,~ 2)\}$$
$$A = \{1\}$$
$$B = \{1\}$$
$$C = \{2\}$$
$$D = \{~\}$$

Comment: This proof is not correct. According to [the third page of this PDF](http://www.davidagler.com/teaching/logic/handouts/Handout8s_PredicateDerivations_ExistentialElimination.pdf), your existential elimination is wrong because you substitute $y$ in your assumption when $y$ is already a free variable in a premise. For the proof above, however, this can be rectified by assuming $Ca \wedge Rax$ right after the premises, doing all of your universal elimination inside of that assumption on $a$, and then doing existential elimination at the end, so steps 21-23 are the same.

Comment: On the other hand, for the statement $\forall \langle x, \ \forall \langle y, \ (Ryx \implies Ay) \implies Dx\rangle \rangle$, this will not work because the above proof really depends on the fact that we have $\forall y \langle Ryx \implies Ay \rangle$ and that we can do universal elimination on $a$ with this statement, but in the statement at the beginning of this comment, we do not have this. This problem was why I said I could prove the former, but not the latter in my original comments on this question.

Comment: I don't really know how to explain it, but I'm going to edit your answer by moving line 12 to line 5, changing the variable to $a$, and then putting everything in within line 5 and line 20 on the inside. Sorry about the weird edit I accidentally just made, I've rolled back to revision 1.

Comment: I am sorry, but your new edit is still not correct because the order of your existential elimination and deduction is wrong. You assume existential statement first, so existential elimination must come after deduction. Sorry, this is because of my bad explanation. I will show you the correct proof very soon, I promise.

Comment: I appreciate you looking at this, I really did have a big problem with the $y$ being present in assumptions prevent the application of existential elimination.  

I guess you are saying
$$\begin{array} {lr}
\exists \langle x,~ P \rangle \\
\quad\quad M  \\
\quad\quad\quad\quad P \\
\quad\quad\quad\quad \vdots \\
\quad\quad\quad\quad Q \\
\quad\quad Q &\exists-\text{Elim} \\
M \implies Q &\text{Deduction} \\
\end{array}$$
is wrong?  I'm gonna have to double check that for sure, you are probably right.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I've put it in the edit above. Notice how we can't easily adjust it to the latter statement anymore because lines 17 and 18 aren't possible, or at least in my view, not trivial to get, for the latter statement.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake in reading Revision 4. It was correct, it just confused me because you used $y$ instead of $a$. For some reason, I read line 7 before line 6, so I thought you had wrote the $Cy \wedge Ryx$ part first when clearly, you wrote it second like you were supposed to. Sorry!

Comment: However, your last part of trying to prove the latter statement was wrong. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization#Generalization_with_hypotheses), in order for universal introduction to be sound, the instance variable must not be in your assumption. However, your instance variable was $z$ and $z$ was clearly in your assumption of line 23 in that proof.

Comment: (23) is not an assumption of (26), it is in a different scope, so there is no variable conflict with the z.  If (23) had been an assumption that (26) depends on then it would have been a conflict.  Or in wikipedia terms, (23) is not a member of $\Gamma$.  I believe everything in it is correct now, moderators forgive me for so many edits, I don't usually use natural deduction, (I tend towards lambda calculus).

Comment: In fact, the latter statement is wrong, so there is no valid proof with its conclusion. Create a model with only the objects 1 and 2. We say $Ax$, $Bx$, $Cx$, $Dx$, and $Ryx$ are all true if and only if $x=2$. These functions satisfy the premises. Now, consider $x=1$, $y=1$, clearly, $\sim Ryx$ since $x \neq 1$ and thus $Ryx \implies Ax$. However, we also have $\sim Dx$ since $x \neq 1$. Thus, we have found $x,y$ such that $(Ryx \implies Ax)\implies Dx$ is false, so $\langle \forall x, \langle y (Ryx \implies Ax) \implies Dx \rangle \rangle$ is false even though the premises are true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41781/discussion-between-noble-mushtak-and-danielv).